# how to put divider line between elements with text in the middle android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, text, divider

i'm trying to design my android application so i need to create a separator line with text in the middle.
i used this code XML to create the separator line:

```
   <View
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
/>
```

but i didn't figure out how to put the text in the middle.

like this : ------- Text ------- but a coherent line

Comment: Could you explain yourself better, or post a link to an image showing the desired result?

Comment: you mean to say want to add separater between the two text?

Comment: i mean : ----- text -----

Comment: You could use a 9 patch background for yout TextView, to achieve that result. OR overlay your TextView on top of the "line" View.

Comment: this works perfectly for different sizes http://stackoverflow.com/a/30413493/2428524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="-----------------------------"
    android:textColor="#ffff00" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/but_book_now"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="This is button"
    android:textColor="#ffff00" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="-----------------------------"
    android:textColor="#ffff00" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For future references, here is a simple solution that resizes properly to the parent's width, and shows a continuous divider line.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp">

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
          android:layout_toStartOf="@id/sep_text"
          android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/sep_text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"
              android:text="misc"/>

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@id/sep_text"
          android:background="@android:color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The text can be accessed by the `sep_text` id.
The height has been fixed to `40dp` but could be changed to `wrap_content`.