# Android : horizontal line with text in middle

Tags: android

I would like to know how to do this horizontal line with text in the middle, look this screenshot :

[image]

Someone have an idea to do that on Android ? I found how to do a horizontal line, but never with text.

Thanks !

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just change the colors to match the ones on your image. I also suggest you use a gradient as the background for those dummy views, it looks a whole lot better then the screenshot if you put a little time into it.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="lala"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tvText"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvText"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thx ! Works perfectly ;) I can't add +1 sorry, but all is ok for me !

Comment: @Asfi you will soon be able to, I think you only need 15 points to +1 posts :) No problem btw

Comment: In case some people have error, don't forget to declare namespace in RelativeLayout : `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 9):

```
public class CenterLineTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

private final Rect mBounds = new Rect();
private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
private int mPadding;
private int mStroke;

public CenterLineTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CenterLineTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CenterLineTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    if (isInEditMode()) {
        return;
    }
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    mStroke = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.divider);
    mPadding = getContext().getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.login_or_padding);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStroke);
    mPaint.setColor(getPaint().getColor());
    getPaint().getTextBounds(getText().toString(), 0, getText().length(), mBounds);
    canvas.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, (getWidth() - mBounds.right) / 2 - mPadding, getHeight() / 2, mPaint);
    canvas.drawLine(mPadding + (getWidth() + mBounds.right) / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2, mPaint);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with only one View for line and one TextView for text. Just add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in XML of TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="or" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[seperator line with text in middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyRZp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

set the width of the view accordingly

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


            <View
            android:id="@+id/topDivider"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/internal"
            android:background="@color/bright_blue"/>

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Middle text here"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/lv_shopName" />


            <View
            android:id="@+id/topDivider"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/internal"
            android:background="@color/bright_blue"/>


            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/linerlayout"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <View
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap conent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"

        android:background="#00000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        Text="abc"/>

 <View
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="wrap conent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"

        android:background="#00000000" />
```