# horizontal line with text in middle with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to achieve the same result as in:
[Android : horizontal line with text in middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413310/android-horizontal-line-with-text-in-middle)

but using `ConstraintLayout`.

No matter what I tried, I can't make the text and the 2 views to be aligned vertically.

I'm not sure if it's because I'm not setting a specific width to the dividers views, but I don't see any other way to let the views take all the free space.

Here's my test layout sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.975"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/left_divider"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/right_divider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.946"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: share screenshot of your layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try below code

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.975"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/left_divider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/right_divider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/right_divider"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/left_divider"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="112dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="243dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

try this :

[image]

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_divider"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/left_divider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/right_divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using single divider view like:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button5" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It Outputs:

[image: Constraint Layout Output]

Comment: That's true only if the background has a solid color, otherwise, it looks bad

Comment: Yea, agreed. That's the condition, if trying to use one `View` divider